# How to get transaction information from PayPal SDK, server-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I can't understand how I suppose to get more information from the PayPal SDK to my server.

Currently, the user makes a transaction from the client-side and then the server-side verifies the transaction really happened.

Here is the server-side route:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('/index.html')
})

app.post('/paypal-transaction-complete', async (req, res) => {
  // 1. Get the order ID from the request body
  const orderID = req.body.orderID
  // 2. Call PayPal to get the transaction details
  let request = new paypal.orders.OrdersGetRequest(orderID)
  let order
  try {
    order = await client().execute(request)
    console.log(order)
  } catch (err) {
    // 3. Handle any errors from the call
    console.error(err)
    return res.status(500).json({
      status: 'failed',
      message: 'Failed to verify the transaction'
    })
  }
  // 4. Save the transaction in your database
  // await database.saveTransaction(orderID);
  // 5. Return a successful response to the client
  return res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    message: 'The transaction been verified'
  })
})
```

And here is the console.log of **order** :

```
{ statusCode: 200,
  headers:        
   { 'cache-control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
     'content-length': '1651',
     'content-type': 'application/json',
     date: 'Wed, 04 Mar 2020 08:00:28 GMT',
     'paypal-debug-id': 'df5886063ee3b',
     connection: 'close' },
  result:
   { id: '9TX85821HJ5742402',
     intent: 'CAPTURE',
     purchase_units: [ [Object] ],
     payer:
      { name: [Object],
        email_address: 'sb-43f9up1139100@personal.example.com',
        payer_id: 'GRP7Y74PGJ392',
        address: [Object] },
     create_time: '2020-03-04T07:59:34Z',
     update_time: '2020-03-04T08:00:23Z',
     links: [ [Object] ],
     status: 'COMPLETED' } }
```

**-- Note --** 
order.result.payer.address retrieve only the country code -

```
 { country_code: 'IL' }
```

I need to get the buyer full shipping details and more info and i don't understand how I can ask that from Paypal... I went over the SDK documents many times and still nothing

Thanks for the helpers!

Answer (score 1):

```
purchase_units: [ [Object] ],
```

The information is in there. You just aren't printing it out.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it! 
I tried to console.log the result.payer.address...
I didn't think the purchase unit has anything related to the address.
And again - Thank you!

Comment: I believe that's the country of the payer's PayPal account, which may or may not be the same as the shipping address country

Comment: Cool. Thanks! I open another question and I will be happy if you could answer on that one as well =)